# deleteRange function only deleting first and last

Tags: java, arrays, range

Currently working on a java program that does a bunch of functions, and one of those functions is to delete a range of alphabetized words. I am using animals as an example.

Here is the display list prior to executing the deleteRange function:

```
cat
chinchilla
horse
mouse
rat
```

I ask the program to delete chinchilla to mouse, but it doesn't include horse.

```
public boolean deleteRange(String start, String stop){
    boolean result = false;
    int begin = Find(start);
    int end = Find(stop);
    while(begin<end){
        Delete(storage[begin]);
        begin++;
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

My delete function:

```
public boolean Delete(String value){
    boolean result = false;
    int location;
    location = Find(value);
    if (location >= 0) {
        moveItemsUp(location);
        numUsed--;
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

My find function:

```
public int Find(String value) {
    int result = -1;
    int index = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while ((index < numUsed) && (!found)) {
        found = (value.equals(storage[index]));
        if (!found)
            index++;
    }
    if (found)
        result = index;
    return result;
}
```

My moveitemsup function:

```
private void moveItemsUp(int start){
    int index;
    for (index = start; index < numUsed-1; index++){
        storage[index] = storage[index+1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are deleting array indices 1 -3 --

After you delete array index 1, your former index 3 now becomes 2 AND you are incrementing "begin" .. So now you delete index 2.. which in this case is mouse .. so horse gets skipped .

Instead, you want to keep the number of elements to delete ( end - begin + 1 )

```
int count = end - begin + 1;
while ( count > 0 ) {
Delete(storage[begin]);
}
```

something along those lines.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, procrastinating. haha. this did work btw.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this if your list is in an ArrayList (no Java stuff on this box so this hasn't been tested) .

```
public boolean deleteRange( String start, String stop ) {
    for(Iterator<String> iter = storage.iterator();iter.hasNext();) {  
        String element = iter.next();  
        if(element.compareTo(start) >= 0 && element.compareTo(stop) <= 0 ) {  
            iter.remove();  
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: using Collection is a good idea, but what were you doing there? `if(element.compareTo(start) >= 0 && element.compareTo(stop) <= 0 )  
            iter.remove(); ` what is that???

Comment: I can't see any problems with this. It is clearly stated that the words are in alphabetical order (i.e. sorted), so the `compareTo` statements are valid.

Comment: This is going with the assumption that the data is sorted, which is something we are given in the question, the compareTo statements will both evaluate to true only when the word is in between the start and end words (inclusive).  It eliminates the need for the Delete, Find, and moveItemsUp functions entirely.

Comment: @MikeWalston didn't see that it is sorted.... sry. Can you somehow edit the answer (whatever) so that I can upvote back.... now it is locked for me to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The problems I can see are:

**problem 1**

you increase `begin` index and "shrink (not really shrink)" the array at same time, after each deletion.

for example

`[a,b,c,d,e,f]`, say you want to delete `b-e` index `1-4`

first you deleted `b (index 1)` then you `moveItemsUp` after deletion. so array is:
`[a,c,d,e,f,f]`, then you `begin++` begin is 2, which pointing `d`, jumped over `c`

**problem 2**

if you fixed problem 1, there is another thing you should consider about, after deletion, the array would be `[a,f,f,f,f,f]` if it is what you wanted.

btw, why not consider to use `LinkedList` ? it should be much faster for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int begin = Find(start);
    int end = Find(stop);
    int count = end - begin;
    for (int i=0; i <= count; i++){
        Delete(storage[begin]);
        result = true;
```

changed some code to this, made it work =)